# How to represent an English police siren sound in writing?

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

Is there a way in which the sound of an English police siren is usually represented in writing?

Comment: Good luck with that. They make a variety of sounds these days, which can change from moment to moment. I would say "hear the siren" or sth.

Comment: I dunno. How is any siren language aware? You might start by using proper spelling. This site is not for doing homework. Please read the Help section at the top right of the screen. You can ask questions on the English Language Learners site but you need to ask a better question and show your own effort on that site too.

Comment: If you must, perhaps sth like *"John heard the wah-wah wah-wah" of a police siren.*

Comment: I don't quite see why this question was so quickly closed. Onomatopoeic expressions **are** a part of English language. Somebody might know whether there exists an expression that has been used with some regularity to render this sound. The question should be open to make it possible for such a person to post an answer.

Comment: @jsw It was closed because as an early comment said, there are a variety of siren sounds used by modern police cars depending on the speed and the traffic conditions. Also, the choice of tones and sounds can vary between police forces in England. So there's no single 'correct' sound.

Comment: It also depends on the audience. "Nee-naw, nee-naw" is dated but also childish. The question needs more context.

Comment: Sirens [wail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wail).

Comment: @WeatherVane [Only sometimes](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/69LjR9DvRnk) (Safe for Work with the sound off)

Comment: @KillingTime 'no single correct answer' does not equal 'opinion', Your comment, with extra details would be a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @jsw29 There was absolutely no effort from the OP and it's obviously homework. That's why, imo.

Comment: @Lambie, true, the original version made it clear that the question arose in an educational setting, but it is hard to believe that representing this sound was the core of the assignment, so I don't think that answering the question would amount to helping the OP cheat on it.

Comment: @jsw29 But we see no effort at all. Plus what happened to the essay? I find the edit to this question artificial. It was originally homework. It's not about cheating, it's about minimum effort, like using caps correctly. "i'mI'm trying to write an essay and I have no idea what I should do convey this sound in writing".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, they indeed do wail, except that is not an onomatopeia.

Comment: Do you mean the old fashioned British two-tone siren, as opposed to the modern/American wailing siren?

Comment: @Lambie are you quite sure that 'wail' is not an onomatopeia. Just try repeating it several times until you catch it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well. it may have started like that but it is a verb in English.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen "wee woo" used for all types of sirens, including ambulance and fire:

> *Wee-woo! Wee-woo!* It was the unmistakable sound of a police car siren. —[Time Sneak](https://books.google.com/books?id=QuVSEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22Wee%20woo%22%20siren&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiio-XblMyEAxXDKFkFHRIhBuo4ChC7BXoECAcQBw#v=onepage&q=%22Wee%20woo%22%20siren&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

**Nee-Naw** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nee-naw), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/12806/nee-naw)) is one common conventional spelling.

Comment: See the comment by Mr Leach below the question.